# Google script - newConditionalFormatRule; whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo not accepting cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a google script but are having trouble with creating the conditional formatting. If I build them in the sheet, there is no issue with setting the range for the conditional format, then set it to "Greater than or equal to" and give it a cell, like =$B$5.

When I build the same thing using the script, it gives me an error that it only accepts numbers and not cells..?

Can anyone help me with this issue? Or is it simply not supported?

```
// What i want to work, but throws an error, since it doesn't get a number.
formatrules.push(Rule1);
  var rule_builder = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo("=$B$9")
  .setBackground("#85e085")
  .setRanges([currentsheet.getRange("H3:H8")])
  .build();


// Something I tried, but it sets it to a static number and not the cell
formatrules.push(Rule1);
  var rule_builder = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(sheet.getRange('B9').getValue())
  .setBackground("#85e085")
  .setRanges([currentsheet.getRange("H3:H8")])
  .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Proposed modification

Since you want a dynamic value what about using the `.whenFormulaSatisfied(String formula)` function?

Here is an example in your application case:

```
var rule_builder = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied("=H3:H8>$B$9")
  .setBackground("#85e085")
  .setRanges([currentsheet.getRange("H3:H8")])
  .build();
```

### Reference

[whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula)

Comment: Seems kind of weird to enter the range again, but for my use case, it works :-)
I'm almost certain there got to be a better way, but for now, this works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikMogensen what do you mean there is a better way? this way defines a custom formula as the conditional formatting `ui` would do. This is the only way.

Comment: @Marios I think I'm just confused by the need to set a custom formula (you can see if you go into conditional formatting), and not uses the same "greater than or equal" in the UI. This might just be a weird design in the API, but they are different if you create it in the UI.

Comment: @HenrikMogensen yes I get that, but like the other answer mentioned, `.whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo` accepts a number, not a formula. It works exactly the same way as the `ui` when you specify that the number should be greater or equal to a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in the `whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo` is of type Number, as specified in the API documentation [seen here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(Number)). You're passing in a string reference to a cell. Instead, you'd have to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B9").getValue()`, as you do in your second attempt. The problem you're running into could be resolved by updating that rule every time the spreadsheet is edited (ie create an onEdit trigger for the function that creates this rule).

Comment: If I create the rule onEdit, I will get a ton of rules stacking on top of each other. I believe this will cause additional issues.
The getValue(), as you say returns the value (once), so it's not quite as handy when you wish to be able to change the B9 cell.
What I wonder, is why I can create a rule referring to the cell if I manually create it, but cant if I use the API. Is it just a flaw in the API, or do they expect people to use another function?

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted answer should remain accepted. This is just a complementary post regarding OP's comment:

> Seems kind of weird to enter the range again

You can define the range once and then use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to incorporate it into the expression:

```
  var rng = "H3:H8";
  var rule_builder = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied(`=${rng}>$B$9`)
  .setBackground("#85e085")
  .setRanges([currentsheet.getRange(rng)])
  .build();
```